# Some links to already visited questions have no :hover-style

Tags: bug, design

In the [list with the recently awarded users with a badge](https://travel.stackexchange.com/badges/20/nice-question) there is a small bug - the questions that are already visited have no font-color change on :hover, but the other links are getting orange(#E6725A).