# Please create a tag, preferably pink, for 'announcements'

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

There are now getting on for 1,000 questions on meta (actually 924), of which 901 are Open and 23 are Closed. Of the Open ones 838 have answers and 63 not. There are 336 questions with Accepted answers. The Acceptance rate (all questions), a pitiful 37%, is even lower than on main (47%).

However Acceptance on meta may be far more relevant than on main, where at stake is merely rep 15+2 per question and an often not very significant indication to others of suitability. On meta there are fewer than 4,000 users, compared with over 35,000 on main. In part because of the reputation minimum ([in theory](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4185/reputation-for-meta-participation-and-displayed-on-meta)) in part because meta users may be self-selecting for activity, meta users should have a better understanding of the use and meaning of ticks than the average main user. I don't know what the average rep per user is on the two but would expect that to be higher on meta than on main.

Acceptance and answer rate (it is [100%](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3368/4995) on main) is more relevant on meta because it [is the part of the site where users discuss the workings and policies of Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).

Lack of Acceptance on meta however can be because the question has been pink tagged. There is no easy way to find for how many questions however, and a pink tag does not necessarily mean no answer nor no Accepted answer.

Lack of an Answer can be because there is nothing *to* answer – for example, though tagged [discussion](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) [Announcement: new mobile ads](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1508/announcement-new-mobile-ads) that post does not include a question and there is not really much to respond to, though the post does include *we're interested in your feedback* (it is from three years ago as has not had an answer so far).

The above make it very difficult to identify issues that are still relevant and have not yet been addressed. For example, selecting the `unanswered` tab does not filter out questions with pink tags and there seems no way to do so as a set (eg they do not all include `status`).

This may explain, in part, why there has been so little action even on posts tagged [bug](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug):

[Some links to already visited questions have no :hover-style](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1225/some-links-to-already-visited-questions-have-no-hover-style) 3 years ago

[Why is the # of tag followers increased when I subscribe AND follow a tag](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1231/why-is-the-of-tag-followers-increased-when-i-subscribe-and-follow-a-tag) 3 years ago

[Bug with posting comments](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1901/bug-with-posting-comments) 2 years ago

[Bug on homepage navigating to my newsletter subscriptions](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2994/bug-on-homepage-navigating-to-my-newsletter-subscriptions) 1 year ago

[Colour of Hot Network Questions](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3656/colour-of-hot-network-questions) 8 months ago

[The tagging system appears to be broken](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4153/the-tagging-system-appears-to-be-broken) 3 days ago

The above extracted from a selection of ten (the other four with pink tags).
For [questions without answers tagged [feature-request]](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfeature-request%5D+closed%3A0+answers%3A0) there are no pink tags, four from 2013 and one recent.

It would help if the `unanswered` tab did not include questions with pink tags and also to have an option to treat all pink tags as a collection when searching but this feature request is to

**create a tag, preferably pink, for 'announcements'**

A lot of questions with no answers on meta, though often tagged [discussion](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) have no answer because there is nothing to answer, or discuss. These 'questions' are announcements, exhortations and rants. There is no way to separate these out at present, but examples include *some* [here](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A101+is%3Aq+answers%3A0). Because there is no way to separate these out at present they are getting in the way of issues that deserve, but are not receiving, attention.

Comment: Why does everything on meta need to be answered? Some issues can just be discussed in comments, or even just dropped due to lack of interact.

Comment: Meh, for me personally Meta is a lot less important than the main site. Simply ask yourself this question: if Travel Meta was purged tomorrow for some reason, would it be a big loss? Probably not. It's therefore irrelevant if some issue is left unanswered - OP can just ask a new one or move on.

Answer (score 3):

The pink tags have been created for very specific meanings. The [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag is probably the most special of them since it is meant to replace the previous FAQ sections the site had (and that were discontinued). It makes sense to have that tag only be added by mods to questions which can truly function as [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) questions rather than anybody. For the remainder, [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) exists which can be transformed into [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) by the mods once they feel the question and answer are ready.

All the other pink (= mod only) tags (except for those which have a function in the SE engine) are those that deal with the status of bug reports or feature requests: [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned), [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro), [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). The final two can also be used as a ‘cheap hack’ to be used on other questions whose discussion has been completed and whose proposals were either accepted or declined but that probably wasn’t the intended idea.

Since anybody can write announcements on meta, I see little use of making the tag mods-only. A non-mod tag [announcements](/questions/tagged/announcements) can be created on meta anytime by anybody who has the required priviledge (that includes you) so if you feel like creating it, go ahead. But it is evident *per se* whether a meta-post is an announcement or not, imho.

Comment: @pnuts You know, [meta.SE] is considered a meta-site and even the SE staff frequently announces stuff there without the need for an [meta-tag:announcement] tag.

Comment: @pnuts [meta-tag:featured] has a function by placing the question in a noticebox on the mainpage. [meta-tag:community-ads] is also special in that it instructs the bot doing the community ad bot to scan this post. They are systemically required imho.